# Create/Replace a Big Query table with a new one generated by a Cloud Function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to get a table from BQ, transform it into a df, apply modifications to it and then upload it back to BQ replacing the former version.

This function is meant to run as a Google Cloud Function.
The Service Account that GCS uses has all the authorisations necessary to access BQ.

I have been using this so far but it's not working:

#### EXTRACT DFP TABLE FROM BQ

```
import google.cloud.bigquery as bigquery
import pandas_gbq as pd

def execute_function(request):

    #Defines Client access & Project to be accessed
    client = bigquery.Client()

    SQL = """
    SELECT LINE_ITEM_NAME, TOTAL_LINE_ITEM_LEVEL_CLICKS
    FROM `DATASET.table_imported` 
    WHERE DATE = DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)
    AND LINE_ITEM_TYPE = 'PRICE_PRIORITY'
    ORDER BY TOTAL_LINE_ITEM_LEVEL_CLICKS  DESC
    LIMIT 1000"""

    query_job = client.query(SQL)

    dfp = query_job.result()

    ### CREATE WRONG NAMING TABLE SORTED BY CLICKS DESCENDING

    dfp = dfp.to_dataframe()

    dfp.columns = ['li_name', 'clicks_number']

    dfp.set_index('li_name', drop = False, inplace = True)

    wrong_naming = pd.DataFrame()
    li_names = []
    clicks_numbers = []

    #Adds line items that have names with number of fields not equal to 7 only if not already present
    for row in range(len(dfp)):
        if len(dfp.iloc[row, 0].split('_')) != 7 and dfp.iloc[row, 0] not in li_names:
            li_names.append(dfp.iloc[row, 0])
            clicks_numbers.append(dfp.iloc[row, 1])

    #Adds created lists to wrong_naming dataframe
    wrong_naming['li_name'] = li_names
    wrong_naming['clicks_number'] = clicks_numbers

    ### EXPORT / SAVE TABLE TO GBQ

    wrong_naming.to_gbq('DATA_LAKE_MODELING_US.wrong_naming', 
                        if_exists='replace')
```

But although it worked when I ran the code on my local system, on the cloud it doesn't.

Here´s the error message that I get: "Error: could not handle the request"

Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: Well, it could be useful to share the code you are using and the message error you are getting if any.

Comment: Yes good point, done !

Comment: FYI You can format your code by selecting the entire thing and using the {} button in the editor to automatically indent the whole thing.

Comment: Have you looked for logs (on Stackdriver)? There should be some more information there about why your function failed.

Comment: @daphshez actually the function does not fail to load I have no logs but when I trigger it simply does not work as I want.

Comment: You will have to explain more precisely what it does or does not do... Probably best to explain that in the question.

Comment: Thank you guys, I have found a solution.

Comment: @QuentinBracq I'm trying to do the exact same thing - do you mind sharing your solution?

Comment: @Mega_Noob so sorry I did not see your comment, actually the only thing that I did was to add the project id when saving to BQ:                          
`wrong_naming.to_gbq(           'DATA_LAKE_MODELING_US.wrong_naming_today',                   if_exists='replace',
project_id = 'YOUR-PROJECT-ID')`